# Problem allocating heap space over 4 GB when calling java "from Python"

Tags: java, python, ram

I am using using os.system call from python to run jar file.
The jar file requires large heap space and thus i am allocating 4 Gb heap space using Xmx.
When i execute the command 
"java -Xms4096m -Xmx4096m -jar camXnet.jar net.txt" 
from command line it executes properly, however when i call it from a python program via os.system, it works only if memory allocated is less than 4Gb, otherwise it fails to execute.
Any solutions?

By fails to execute i mean that A command window appears indicating that os.system has been called and then it disappears, i will check for the error code if any being returned. however no problems are encountered if xmx,xms are set to lower value.

Ok i checked both version and there is a difference The one being called via python is Java HotSpot Client VM mixed mode,sharing while one being called via normal command line is Java HotSpot 64 bit server

How do make os.system in python call the correct one that is the 64 bit server.

UPDATE: I tried using subprocess module as yet the version of java return is same as that from os.system

Comment: Add more detail. What does "fail to execute" mean? Does it fail to start, or start but fail in a way you are sure depends on a failure to set the heap size?

Comment: Sounds like you have a 32-bit version of Java somewhere on your path, and that's what Python is picking up.

Comment: thats a possibility, but os.system calls it via standard windows cmd system.
Also there is no 32 bit version of java deliberately placed in the path.
And when i execute it via normal command line (" which has same environment") it does executes properly.

Comment: @akshayubhat: if "there is a difference", you need to find out why you're getting one  JVM from the command line and a different JVM from within `subprocess`.  Your environments must be different.  Can you add that information to your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to be sure without knowing more detail - like which OS you're on - but my guess is that you're using a 32-bit version of Python which means that when you launch Java, you're also getting the 32-bit version which has a heap size limit of 4GB.

To test if this is the case, compare the output of `java -version` when run from the command line and when run from your Python script.

Comment: Ok i checked both version
and there is a difference
The one being called via python
is
Java HotSpot Client VM  mixed mode,sharing
while one being called via normal command line is 
Java HotSpot 64 bit server

Comment: So it sounds like I may be right.  Check if you're using a 32-bit or 64-bit version of Python.

Comment: Yes i am using 32 bit python 2.5
Python 2.5.4 (r254:67916, Dec 23 2008, 15:10:54) [MSC v.1310 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

Comment: OK, so you need to download 64-bit Python and try again.  Or it may be possible to solve this by tweaking the PATH variable on Windows before you launch Java.  Perhaps try giving the full path the 64-bit Java in your Python script to see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem launching 64bit Java from 32bit python. I solved the problem using Dave Webb's suggestiong of putting the full path to 64bit Java.exe in the python script. This worked fine so it is not necessary to use 64 bit Python

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, but try using [subprocess.call()](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess#subprocess.call) instead of os.system(), [it is preferred](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.system) and may handle the issue you are experiencing. I'm curious to know if it does...

Comment: No it still returns the same version of Java "Java HotSpot Client VM mixed mode,sharing" and not the 64 bit server